# Homology of unit tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. I want to compute the homology of $S(E)$ (the unit tangent bundle).

By the Gysin sequence, I am able to compute the cohomology groups. However, I cannot apply Poincaré duality, because S(E) is a manifold with boundary (I have not learned the theorem for manifolds with boundary).

Can anyone give me a clue, please?

Comment: $S(E)$ is a closed manifold (it has no boundary).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to know the dimension of such manifold?

Comment: The fiber of $S(E) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ is $S^{2n-1}$ so $S(E)$ has dimension $4n-1$.